# How do I create a List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> out of a Map<String, Integer>?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

So I know how to create a List of Map values
`new ArrayList<String, Integer>(map.getValues());`
Or from entry set `map.entrySet()`
However there doesn't seem to be a similar way to add a list of Map.Entry<String, Integer>
Is there a way to do this so I can write it all in just a return statement?

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

public List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> getWordList(){
        return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map);
}
```

This doesn't work. But what does?

Comment: You can try `return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet())`

Comment: Best to assign a `TreeMap` to `NavigableMap` rather than `Map` if you want to access the features related to sorting.

Answer (score 2):

`entrySet` returns a `Set` and not a `List`, which means that the map's keys may or may not be in order.

However, in the case of `TreeMap` [the JavaDoc says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet()) the following about it:

> Returns a `Set` view of the mappings contained in this map.
>
> The set's iterator returns the entries in ascending key order.

Apparently, `entrySet()` guarantees the mappings to be in the same order as the `TreeMap`. In short, you could just use it anywhere where a `Collection` is required. Creating a `List` is then trivial:

```java
new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet())
```

or

```java
List.copyOf(map.entrySet())
```